# Toolchain for Topic Maps data export

Tags: data-modeling, tex, topic-maps

I am planning to typeset data which are stored in a Topic Map. The topic map can be exported in a variety of xml and json Topic Maps formats. I would like to use ConTeXt for typesetting. Obviously it's possible to use XSLT to get a printable version of data, but perhaps there are already better solutions. Can you suggest any TMQL tools for instance? Or maybe a completely different approach?

Comment: Actually this is not an exact answer to my question but I managed to solve the problem by avoiding export to external Topic Map altogether. I am using Topincs and fortunately  Topincs makes it very easy to deal with the data using its virtual programming interface. I managed to create a webservice which serves TeX (specifically ConTeXt) source which is ideal for my needs. However, if anyone has other ideas I am very curious to read them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost three years have passed and since I have just managed to successfully finish a big project which has sparked this question, I think I can share some of my experiences.

The topic map was created in the Topincs program and my first idea was to export the topic map in one of common formats, transform it and typeset the output of the transformation. In the end I have used native Topincs API to generate a source text for  ConTeXt. It is quite simple as Topincs generates a set of functions for each topic type which can be used in definitions of web services. Of course, it might be possible to define any number of web services needed. I have settled just for one which exports the complete text with ConTeXt commands included ready for typesetting.

For another project I have set up  a toolchain in which data is output by a Topincs service  as a yaml file and is used directly by middleman program which generates a website from the topic map created in Topincs.